# Call a async:false ajax inside a async:true ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have two ajax call. First one is asynchronous, second is synchronous. If I put a synchronous call inside a success function, then what will happened. Is it block any event from other places when synchronous execute.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www..../k.php",
        data: dataString,
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "http://www..../s.php",
                   data: dataString,
                   crossDomain: true,
                   cache: false,
                   async: false,                       
                   success: function (response) {}
                  });
         });
```

Comment: hey, if you don't ant to block or stop JavaScript execution, just make the async : true and that you will have to wait for the response

Comment: But in that case both ajax give me free value. If i print( 1 to 10) by using both async : true ajax those are overlap each othe. Than it give many combination in every time. So i need synchronous execution but don't block other event. I also need two ajax in this purpose.

Comment: If the calls are nested then they will be made and resolved consecutively. There's no need for either of them to be synchronous. This is a wrong solution to whatever the real problem is.